# Function that satisfies intermediate value property and $f(x) ≤ f(y)$ for all $x<y$ is continuous

Tags: analysis, continuity

> A function $f$ is increasing on $A$ if $f(x) ≤ f(y)$ for all $x<y$
>   in $A$. Show that if $f$ is increasing on $[a, b]$ and satisfies the intermediate value property, then $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$.

My attempt:
Supose it is not continuous. Take $|x-c| < \sigma$ but $|f(x)-f(c)| \ge \epsilon_0$
than $|f(x)| \ge \epsilon_0 + |f(c)|$, so $f(x) >f(c)$ which is false.

Comment: What are $\epsilon_0$ and $\sigma$? (and $x$, and $c$...)

Comment: HInt. Try a direct proof. Given $x$ and $\epsilon$ find a $\delta$. Drawing a picture might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: show that, for every $c\in(a,b)$, both
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)
$$
exist finite. For instance,
$$
\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\sup_{a\le x<c}f(x)
$$
What if the two limits differ?

Finish up with the special cases of $c=a$ and $c=b$.